# Python: why is this array an object instead of a float?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, object, types

I am trying to order data and make an array for each unique ID. 
Data I'm using are columns of integers/floats or empty cells (NaN).

I will paste a simplified version of the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dtypes = {'starttime': 'str', 'endtime': 'str', 'hr': 'float', 'sofa_24hours': 'float'}
parse_dates = [2,3]
fields = [0,1,11,12,13,14,15,34,35,36]
reader = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0, names=headers, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates, usecols=fields)
print("Started loading data...")

df = pd.DataFrame(data=reader)
ids = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
id_list = np.unique(ids)
x = df.iloc[:, 2:6].astype(float)
y = df.iloc[:, 7].astype(float)
t = df.iloc[:, 0].astype(float)

x_data = []
y_data = []
t_data = []

for i in range(0,len(id_list)):
    idx = np.where(ids==id_list[i])[0]
    t_data.append(t.values[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1])
    x_data.append(x.values[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1,:])
    y_data.append(y.values[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1])

    if np.mod(i,1000)==0:
        print("Data association... {}%".format(np.round(100*i/len(id_list))))

print("Finished loading data!")
```

Now, when I check for the type:

```
In [1]: y.dtype
Out[1]: dtype('float64')
```

That seems about right. Then I cut the data into batches using:

```
batch_size=64
W=5

idx_pt = np.random.randint(W,len(x_data),batch_size)
idx_t = [np.random.randint(0,len(x_data[i])-W-1) for i in idx_pt]

batch_x = np.array([x_data[idx_pt[i]][idx_t[i]:idx_t[i]+W,:] for i in range(0,len(idx_pt))])
batch_y = np.array([y_data[idx_pt[i]] for i in range(0,len(idx_pt))])
```

When I check for dtype:

```
In [2]: batch_x.dtype
Out[2]: dtype('float64')

In [3]: batch_y.dtype
Out[3]: dtype('O')
```

Why is batch_y treated as an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the last array (batch_y) was created from a list which contains numpy arrays of different length.

I don't have your data, but the following code produces both `batch_x` and `batch_y` as object arrays:

```
import numpy as np

x= np.random.randint(0, high = 10, size=[300,300])
y = np.array(np.random.randint(0, high = 10, size=300), dtype=np.float64)


id_list = np.random.randint(0, high = 10, size=20)
ids = id_list

x_data = []
y_data = []

for i in range(0,len(id_list)):
    idx = np.where(ids==id_list[i])[0]
    x_data.append(x[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1,:])
    y_data.append(y[idx[0]:idx[-1]+1])


batch_size=64
W=5

idx_pt = np.random.randint(W,abs(len(x_data)),batch_size)
idx_t = [np.random.randint(0,abs(len(x_data[i])-W-1)) for i in idx_pt]

batch_x = np.array([x_data[idx_pt[i]][idx_t[i]:idx_t[i]+W,:] for i in range(0,len(idx_pt))])
batch_y = np.array([y_data[idx_pt[i]] for i in range(0,len(idx_pt))])
```

The reason is that `y_data` already contains arrays of different length:

```
>>> y_data[0]
array([0., 9., 9., 8., 2., 1., 7., 7., 8., 0.])
>>> y_data[1]
array([9., 9., 8., 2., 1., 7., 7., 8.])
>>> y_data[3]
array([8., 2., 1., 7., 7.])
>>> y_data[4]
array([2., 1., 7., 7., 8., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Please check your input dataframe and what you are actually putting into `x_data` and `y_data`.

Comment: Correct, y_data contains arrays of different lengths. However, the length is the same as x_data: `len(y_data[0]) = 74`, `len(x_data[1]) = 143`, `len(x_data[0]) = 74`, `len(x_data[1])= 143`

Comment: Then `batch_y` will have object dtype. You can check dtype of `np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])` and `np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2]])` , First one will be int, the second will be object.

Comment: For me personally it's hard to guess without having the input data (original dataframe), but if you indeed are creating arrays from chunks of different length, then the real question is why `batch_x` is still float.

Comment: I figured it out. It turns out I didn't cut `data_y` in pieces of equal length `w`. This is the working code: `batch_y = np.array([y_data[idx_pt[i]][idx_t[i]+W] for i in range(0,len(idx_pt))])`. `dtype = float64`